# Replace a specific character with blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I replace 'a' to blank?

```
`Name`              `ID`
----------------------------------
`b,c,d,e,abb,a`     `1`
`b,c,d,a,e,abb`     `2`  
`a,b,c,d,a,e,abb`   `3`
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: In addition to showing desired results, specifying version will help you get the best solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to add a `,` to the beginning and end of each `Name`, then replace every occurence of `',a,'` with `','`, then trim the result of the `,`:

```
update table_name
set Name = trim(',' from replace(concat(',', Name, ','), ',a,', ','));
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=325710a5ffba0f6f616b4989460e1083)

Or if you just want to do a `select` without changing the rows:

```
select trim(',' from replace(concat(',', Name, ','), ',a,', ',')) as Name, ID
from table_name;
```

To address @Iptr's comment, if there can be consecutive `a` such as `a, a, ...`, you could use `STRING_SPLIT` to get rows from comma-separated values, then filter out where the value is `a`, then `STRING_AGG` and `group by` to get the comma separated values back:

```
select ID, STRING_AGG(u.Value, ',') as Name
from table_name
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (Name, ',') u
where Value <> 'a'
group by ID
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae1c0715cad177a0c2efc2606959a5a5)

Comment: Not exactly. 'abb' or 'bab' <> 'a'

Comment: I want to replace 'a,' and ',a' and ',a,' with blank

Comment: @AaronBertrand you're right, thanks! Fixed my answer for sql server.

Comment: Still not working. Check the 2nd and 3rd rows. It incorrectly gives **b,c,de,abb**

Comment: @alireza Please add desired results to the question (like you’ve already been asked) so people don’t have to _guess_ if their solution gives the right answer. Please read all the links here: https://sqlblog.org/ask

Comment: @AaronBertrand, you need to address your comment to the OP, i.e. alireza heydari

Comment: @miriamka yes, realized and fixed

Comment: @Iptr thank you! I addressed the issue with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on tokenization via XML/XQuery.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Steps:

1. We are tokenizing a string of tokens via XML.
2. XQuery FLWOR expression is filtering out the 'a' token.
3. Reverting it back to a string of tokens.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('b,c,d,e,abb,a'),
('b,c,d,a,e,abb'),
('a,b,c,d,a,e,abb');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT t.* 
, REPLACE(c.query('
   for $x in /root/r/text()
   return if ($x = "a") then ()
      else data($x)
   ').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), SPACE(1), @separator) AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+
| ID |     tokens      |   Result    |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | b,c,d,e,abb,a   | b,c,d,e,abb |
|  2 | b,c,d,a,e,abb   | b,c,d,e,abb |
|  3 | a,b,c,d,a,e,abb | b,c,d,e,abb |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
SELECT ID,Name, REPLACE(Name, 'a', ' ') 
FROM tableName;
```

Comment: Not exactly. 'abb' or 'bab' <> 'a'